# Does a VMware virtual machine take up memory when off

Tags: vmware, boot-camp

Alright.  So I have a BootCamp partition on my mac, but it's kinda annoying switching every week since I have assignments to do for my class on the Windows and I'm coding on Xcode on my Mac mostly.  I happen to have VMware at my disposal, but I don't want to remove my BootCamp partition to save memory.  So... is it a good idea to have both a BootCamp partition and a Windows OS on VMware Fusion?  Ty

Comment: The title of this post and the actual question don't match. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Oh.. yeah... sorry.. I meant to say that I just don't want to waste too much memory, so does the virtual machine take memory if I turn it off?  If not, then it's probably not a good idea.  Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The windows virtual machine will only use memory when it is running.  When you power down the windows virtual machine, the memory will be available by your Mac once again.  The same behavior is true for all system resources such as CPU.

Also by memory I assume you mean RAM. I don't understand how removing a boot camp partition would save memory.

Comment: Oh no... I think the VMware definition of memory is hard drive.  Anyway, I gave BootCamp 128G.  Will that still be used even if the partition is off?

Comment: You are talking about disk space.  In Vmware when you create your virtual machine you set how large you want the disk space to be.  This will always be taken up while the virtual machine is on the system, running or not. You can kinda think of this as another boot camp partition. You would have to delete the VM to get that disk space back. For example if you created a VM with 50GB of disk space, your available space on your MAC partition would go down by 50GB.  Once you delete the VM it would go back up by 50GB.